# the delivery report includes the original letter

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, pop3

We have installed windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise and Microsoft Exchange 2010. The clients use Outlook
from Microsoft Office 2010. if we use POP3 protocol between exchange and user then the delivery report from server come with the included original letter. Why does this happend? Can anybory explain this situation?

Comment: Tip: begin your sentences with uppercase to make your general text quality better.